# Internet connection problem, believe it's due to lack of initialization by Ubuntu 22.04 on startup

Tags: networking, 22.04, vpn, startup

Several weeks ago, Ubuntu 22.04 was installed on two PCs, which were then customized with Slimjet browser, ProtonVPN, Autokey, Timeshift, and little else.  Both systems operated flawlessly.  Yesterday, I shut down the HP. When re-powered, it would only connect to the internet through a live USB.  The basic internet settings (upper right corner) says everything is good, but neither Firefox nor Slimjet will connect, nor will ProtonVPN connect.  I suspect the power-off trapped VPN settings which aren't appropriate for startup.  As a newbie, it appears to me the problem could be with either Ubuntu or ProtonVPN (or how they interact).

I'd rather not do a Timeshift recovery.

Any edits or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Clarifying: I don't want to do a recovery in case there is info present which might suggest a change to some code.  The other PC is working with no problem, nor do I expect any.

Answer (score 0):

I found a clue in protonvpn instructions for deleting protonvpn: "Look for any connections that begin with prefix pvpn- This usually includes pvpn-killswitch and pvpn-ipv6leak-protection, and may include pvpn-routed-killswitch. Delete all these connections using the following command:

nmcli connection delete [connection name]"

---

What appeared was something referencing "ipv4".  I deleted that connection and rebooted.  Shazaam!

---

I interpret this to mean that Ubuntu was restarting a process that was running when the power-off occurred. The communication was blocked by this IPV4 reference since it didn't present a normal startup condition.